# I was installing Expo-cli for running React native app but error below happened . how to fix this?

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

npm:the version of expo doesnot come.I will thanful if u could solve my problem

````
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead```

changed 1710 packages, and audited 1711 packages in 8m
110 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
23 vulnerabilities (20 moderate, 3 high)
To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
Run `npm audit` for details.
.........................
<>
````

Comment: There is nothing to fix, expo installed successfully, unless there were more errors in the console.

Comment: @Eloi thanks man..but u know it have to show the version of expo in it...so there is no version .
I will check it again any way thanks

Comment: Yes, `expo-cli` installed successfully. However, do we need to install the individual packages which NPM marked as deprecated?

Comment: @Eloi IDK your question...but expo didn't install yet...when I enter expo init that don't work too